# MS SQL JOINing a Table to Itself

Tags: sql

```
Col1 | Col2 |
10     NULL
20     NULL
30     NULL
20     NULL
```

I have a Table and I want to update each row of Col2 with the follwoing condition: Some scaler number `X/(Count of the value from Col1)`. That is if `X = 8` then I should have the follwoing values `8/1 , 8/2, 8/1, 8,2 and so on..`

I am doing the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT [Table].Col1
    FROM [Table]
    INNER JOIN [Table] T ON [Table].Id = T.Id
    WHERE [Table].Col1 = T.Col1
    )
```

Can you point out my mistake please?

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT t1.Col1, 8 / t2.cnt
FROM [Table] t1 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Col1, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   From [Table]
   GROUP BY Col1
) t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col2
```

The above query uses a derived table that contains the count per `Col1` value. Using this count we can do the math required for each row of the original table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works now :)